# How to pause/play/stop a dynamically loaded SWF using SWFLoader component in Flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a situation where I am loading an SWF (using URL as source) using the SWFLoader component in Flex 4, and now I need to implement Pause/Play and Stop functionality. Any help on this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the loaded content through the property `SWFLoader.content` and call its methods to play or pause it. Assuming "swfLoader" is the id of SWFLoader component and the loaded content has a public method `play()`, here's what the ActionScript code will look like:

```
(swfLoader.content as MovieClip).play();
```

Comment: Hey Omer, I am aware of how to load/play and unload/stop, the real problem is with setting pause and resume from the point paused.

Comment: @MohammedKhan You should be able to capture the current frame store it in a variable then gotoAndPlay with the stored "framestamp" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame